# FFT values of webaudio's AnalyserNode are outside range

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use Web-Audio's Analyser Node and keep getting weird results from it.

The code:

```
var self = this;
var bufferSize = 512;
var spectrum = new Float32Array(bufferSize/2);

self.analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
self.analyser.fftSize = bufferSize;
self.analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
self.analyser.minDecibels = -120;
self.analyser.maxDecibels = 0;
self.analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(spectrum);
source.connect(self.analyser);
```

Even though I explicitly set the values of the max and min decibels, I still get values that are less than -120, for example, -180.

Also, when I `console.log` the analyser, I see that the values did in fact change, but the FFT still gives me lower values than expected.

I'm using a stereo mp3 file to test it, could this be an issue?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Min and max decibels only affect the getByteFrequencyData values, not the getFloatFrequencyData values.  "The minimum/maximum power value in the scaling range for the FFT analysis data for conversion to unsigned byte values."

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode): AnalyserNode.minDecibels
Is a double value representing the minimum power value in the scaling range for the FFT analysis data, for conversion to unsigned byte/float values — basically, this specifies the minimum value for the range of results when using getFloatFrequencyData() or getByteFrequencyData().

Comment: That's an error in the Mozilla documentation.  The spec (http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AnalyserNode-maxDecibels) specifically says "for conversion to unsigned byte values", with nothing about float values.

Comment: I submitted a fix to the Mozilla doc page.

Comment: Moz fixed it... a double value representing the minimum power value in the scaling range for the FFT analysis data, for conversion to unsigned byte values — basically, this specifies the minimum value for the range of results when using getByteFrequencyData().